# Optimization of double loop

Tags: matlab, optimization, for-loop

I have written a code where i have to control, if the position (x,y) (saved in the Matrix Mat) is inside of a circular object which is centered at (posx,posy). If so the point gets a value val otherwise its zero. 
 
My Code looks like this but as a matter of fact it is advertised to NOT use loops in matlab. Since i use not 1 but 2 loops, i was wondering if there is a more effective way for solving my problem.

```
Mat = zeros(300); %creates my coordinate system with zeros
...
for i =lowlimitx:highlimitx %variable boundary of my object
   for j=lowlimity:highlimity
      helpsqrdstnc = abs(posx-i)^2 + abs(posy-j)^2; %square distance from center
      if helpsqrdstnc < radius^2
         Mat(i,j)= val(helpsqrdstnc); 
       end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the usual way to optimize matlab code is to vectorize the operations. This is because built in functions and operators is in general much faster. For your case this would leave you with this code:

```
Mat = zeros(300); %creates my coordinate system with zeros
...
xSq = abs(posx-(lowlimitx:highlimitx)).^2;
ySq = abs(posy-(lowlimity:highlimity)).^2;

helpsqrdstnc = bsxfun(@plus,xSq,ySq.'); %bsxfun to do [xSq(1)+ySq(1),xSq(2)+ySq(1),...; xSq(1)+ySq(2),xSq(2)+ySq(2)...; ...]
Mat(helpsqrdstnc < radius^2)= val(helpsqrdstnc(helpsqrdstnc < radius^2));
```

where `helpsqrdstnc` must be the same size as Mat. There may also be neseccary to do a reshape here, but you will notice that by yourself if you get a column vector.

This does of course assume that `radius`, `posx` and `posy` is constant, but reading the question this seems to be the case. However, I do not know exactly how val looks, so it I have not managed to test the code. I also think that `val(helpsqrdstnc)` is tedious, since this refer to the distance, which does not neseccarily need to be an integer.

Comment: Wont `helsqrdstnc` be a different size to `Mat`?
And a note for @The Minion: For loops aren't necessarily bad in Matlab nowadays, the JIT compilation is very good at dealing with for loops, and in some cases vectorisation can slow code down! It's worth confirming that this vectorised code is indeed faster than the for loop version (in particular memory usage can slow vectorised code down).

Comment: Yes I agree, especially with smaller vectors, but it isn't always the case (as it used to be without JIT), so it's always worth checking if possible to make sure.

Comment: @David I use matlab version R2013a and my experience is that for loops in almost every case should be avoided and this is such a case. About the size of the matrix, I see what you mean and I will edit the code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @David well I see your point. I guess it make sense comparing the runtime for both methods. As I mentioned earlier, I guess this code will run faster when vectorized, especially since mostly built in operators are used, but you can never say for sure before the code is tested +1

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, for the question. yes `posx posy and radius` are constants which are given as input. And `val(helpsqrdstnc)` is a function which returns a computed value which depends only on the real distance from the center and global variables.

Comment: Ok, then you must make sure that your function can deal with matrices. Otherwise it should be fine. However, if you think that your code is to slow and `val` is a function, then I would assume that the code inside `val` is the one that slows down your code the most. You should run the profiler and check what takes up the time.

Comment: @TheMinion The global variables are at fault at slowing down applications at times too. If you can, try to avoid and see if it helps in performance.

Comment: @patrik I tried with some `meshgrid` technique - `[xv1,xv2] = meshgrid(lowlimitx:highlimitx,lowlimity:highlimity), helpsqrdstnc = abs(posx-xv2).^2 + abs(posy-xv1).^2`. Not sure if this is any faster than `bsxfun` one, which definitely looks sweet! +1